# Warum wird das Wort "folgend" mit keinem Artikel benutzt?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Warum sagt man auf Deutsch:

> Ich habe folgendes Problem.

Und nicht eher:

> Ich habe **das** folgende Problem.

genau wie:

> ich sehe **den** rennenden Mann.

Comment: Sorry, but you can say "Ich habe das folgende Problem: ...". Why do you think, one can not?

Comment: Both are totally valid and it depends on the speaker, which one to use and what exactly he wants to stress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da die Frage ja war, *warum* man das sagt:

Ein Teil der Antwort ist, dass Sprache nicht Regeln folgt, die vorgesetzt sind, sondern dass Regeln, die im Grammatikbuch stehen, abgeleitet werden aus der aktuellen, lebendigen Sprachpraxis. Bestimmte Wendungen verbreiten sich,  auch wenn sie solcherart ermittelten Regeln entgegenstehen, wohl dem Faulheitsprinzip folgend oder auch durch Orientierung an vermeintlich autoritativen Vorbildern. (Der emsige Grammatiker ergänzt seine Regeln dann gerne mit einer Unterregel, um die Abweichung zu legalisieren.)

So sagen Leute ja auch massenhaft

> Am Ende diesen Jahres...

wo es eigentlich (den sonstigen Regeln folgend) heißen müsste

> Am Ende dieses Jahres...

denn es heißt ja auch nicht

> *Am Ende diesen Hundes ist ein Schwanz

sondern richtig und regeltreu

> Am Ende dieses Hundes ist ein Schwanz.

Wer jetzt sagt, "Hund ist aber männlich, Jahr ist sächlich", dann bitteschön:

> *Am Ende diesen Eichhörnchens ist ein buschiger Schwanz.

**Besondere Verwendung von "folgende"**

Wenn wir nun eine Regel aufstellen wollen für die abweichende Verwendung von *folgende* (nämlich ohne Artikel), können wir uns auf folgende (!) Wendungen stützen, die sehr verbreitet sind und von den Sprachnutzern auch nicht als ungrammatisch angesehen werden:

> Arzt: Nehmen Sie bitte folgende Medikamente ein...
>
> Zoologie-Professor: Achten Sie bitte auf folgende Besonderheiten des Amazonas-Eichhörnchens...
>
> Betriebsanleitung: Folgende Operationen dürfen mit dem Gerät nur unter Aufsicht eingewiesenen Personals durchgeführt werden...
>
> Staatsanwalt: Ihnen werden folgende Vergehen zur Last gelegt...
>
> Hinweisschild im Zoo: Die Eisbärenwäsche findet an folgenden Tagen statt...

In all diesen Fällen könnte man auch "die folgenden/den folgenden"  sagen. Aber man tut es (sehr häufig) nicht. Ich nehme doch stark an, dass folgende (!) Ursache vorliegt: Bequemlichkeit, die zur Gewohnheit wird und damit schließlich zur Regel.

Comment: Sooo, sagt man das? Falsch ist es aber trotzdem. Und nein, dafür hat der "emsige Grammatiker" noch keine Unterregel erfunden.

Comment: Man sagt es, leider, und ich würde sagen, in 99 Prozent aller Fälle. Ich habe noch nie jemanden getroffen (außer mir selbst), der "am Ende dieses Jahres" schreibt. - Zum emsigen Grammatiker: Ich konzidiere, dass es heißen müsste "der emsige deskriptive Grammatiker".

Comment: Dann schau' mal da: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ende+diesen+jahres%2Cende+dieses+jahres&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CEnde%20diesen%20Jahres%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEnde%20dieses%20Jahres%3B%2Cc0 Deine persönliche Statistik wird nicht bestätigt. Vielleicht kennst du auch einfach nur die falschen Leute...

Comment: Also, würdest du sagen, dass beim by-the-book-Deutsch, "Ich habe das folgende..." eher richtiger ist, als "Ich habe folgendes...", zu sagen? Ich verstehe schon, dass heutzutage sind die beiden richtig, aber nun laut deutscher Grammatik will ich wissen.

Comment: @tofro  Google Ngram ist keine gute Quelle hier. Weiß Gott, was die da eingescannt haben. Jedenfalls nicht die Geschäftskorrespondenz des realen Lebens. In gut lektorierten Büchern und von guten Redakteuren redigierten Zeitungen wird man natürlich eher die korrekte Form "dieses Jahres" finden.

Comment: Nix für ungut, aber ich behaupte, es ist eine bessere Quelle als Christian Geiselmanns Bekannte...

Comment: @sermonionx   "Ich habe folgendes Problem" ist eine Wendung aus der Alltagssprache, v.a. auch der Sprache in Wirtschaftsorganisationen (vulgo Firmen). Da schleifen sich manche Dinge ein, die bequemer und kürzer sind als die korrekte oder auch stilistisch bessere Form. Der Grund ist Bequemlichkeit.

Comment: @tofro   Kleine Korrektur: Meine Bekannten sagen so was nicht. Aber ich lese es laufend in Geschäftskorrespondenz (von mir ansonsten unbekannten Personen).

Comment: "diesen Jahres" ist mittlerweile schon so gebräuchlich, dass es wohl keinen Sinn mehr hat, es als inkorrekt zu brandmarken. Sprache verändert sich nun mal. In diesem Fall scheinen die Demonstrativa ihre ererbten Endungen abzulegen und in die schwache Deklination überzugehen. Sprachwissenschaftlich interessant, so etwas quasi "live" zu beobachten.

Comment: @RHa  Das ist ja weitgehend das, was ich (bezogen auf die Ausgangsfrage) auch sagte.

Comment: Das Weglassen des Artikels vor bestimmten Adjektiven scheint kein neues Phänomen zu sein. Bei Kafka findet sich "Wer leiht jetzt sein Pferd her zu solcher Fahrt?". Womöglich war das Weglassen des Artikels frühers sogar verbreiteter als heute.

Answer (score 6):

Die Annahme, *folgend* würde nur ohne Artikel verwendet, ist nicht korrekt. Folgende (die folgenden) Varianten sind gleichfalls möglich:

> folgendes Problem
>   
>   das folgende Problem

Das ist bei anderen Adjektiven genauso:

> beide Varianten
>   
>   die beiden Varianten
>
> mit ausgestreckter Hand
>   
>   mit der ausgestreckten Hand
>
> bei drohendem Unwetter
>   
>   bei dem drohenden Unwetter
>
> ...

In einigen Fällen klingt nur eine Variante korrekt, wie bei

> ich sehe den rennenden Mann
>   
>   <s>ich sehe rennenden Mann</s>

Aber bei „folgendes Problem“ ist beides möglich.

Comment: "bei drohendem Unwetter" ist aber nicht das gleiche wie "bei dem drohenden Unwetter". Im zweiten Fall muss es schon eines geben, bei ersterem nicht.

Comment: @IngoBochmann Genau.

Answer (score 2):

Deutsch ist eine Sprache, in der Nomen sowohl mit als auch ohne Artikelwort stehen können. Die Regeln, wann ein Artikelwort stehen muß und wann nicht, sind aber nicht einfach anzugeben.

(Um die Zahl der Beispiele zu reduzieren, benutze ich folgende Schreibkonvention: **(die)* heißt, daß der Artikel nicht fehlen darf und *(großes)* heißt, daß das Adjektiv optional ist. Der Stern hat wie üblich die Bedeutung, daß das Beispiel ungrammatisch ist.)

## Appellative Nomen und Stoffbezeichnungen

Appellative Nomen im Singular brauchen ein Artikelwort.

> Wir suchen *(eine) Wohnung.
>
> Wie gefällt dir *(die) Wohnung?

Stoffbezeichnungen können im Singular ohne Artikel stehen; stehen sie mit Artikel, ändert sich die Bedeutung. Sie verhalten sich dann wie appellative Nomen.

> 1. Ich trinke gern Wein.
> 2. Trinkst du den Wein noch?
> 3. Trinkst du die Flasche Wein noch?

Der erste Satz spricht von Wein allgemein, im Unterschied zu anderen Getränken. Der zweite bezieht sich zum Beispiel auf eine angebrochene Flasche Wein, die im Kühlschrank steht, wird also wie der dritte verstanden.

*Problem* ist ein appellatives Nomen. Es kann im Singular nicht ohne Artikel stehen.

> Wir haben *(ein) (großes) Problem.
>
> Verstehst du *(das) (vorliegende) Problem?

## Artikelwörter, Adjektive sowie starke und schwache Flexion

Adjektive können stark oder schwach sein.

> 1. gut**er** Wein (starke Endung am Adjektiv)
> 2. ein groß**es** Problem (starke Endung am Adjektiv)
> 3. dies**es** groß**e** Problem (schwache Endung am Adjektiv)

Wie man sieht, tritt die starke Endung genau dann auf, wenn kein Artikelwort (1.) oder ein endungsloses Artikelwort (2.) vorangeht. Wenn ein Artikelwort mit Endung vorangeht, tritt die schwache Endung auf (3.).

Manche Wörter können sowohl als Artikelwörter als auch als Adjektive auftreten.

> 1. mit *einem* schwierigen Problem
> 2. mit diesem *einen* Problem

Im ersten Beispiel steht der unbestimmte Artikel. Daß es sich um ein Artikelwort handelt, kann man auch daran erkennen, daß das Adjektiv die schwache Endung trägt. Im zweiten Beispiel steht das Zahladjektiv; es hat die schwache Endung.

## Beantwortung der Ausgangsfrage

Mit den Beobachtungen, die wir gesammelt haben, ergibt sich folgendes Bild.

> 1. folgendes gesellschaftlich**e** Problem
> 2. das folgende gesellschaftliche Problem
> 3. ein weiteres daraus folgendes Problem

Im ersten Fall handelt es sich bei *folgendes* um ein Artikelwort, da das folgende Adjektiv *gesellschaftliche* die schwache Endung trägt; im zweiten und dritten um ein Adjektiv. Der erste Fall entspricht -- ohne das Adjektiv -- dem Ausgangsbeispiel.

Ein Warnhinweis. Man findet in freier Wildbahn auch Beispiele wie die folgenden:

> Wir haben folgend**es** groß**es** Problem. (anstelle von: *große*)
>
> Dem liegt folgend**er** grundsätzlich**er** Gedanke zugrunde. (anstelle von: *grundsätzliche*)

Ob man um derentwillen den obigen Erklärungsansatz aufgeben will, sei jedem selber überlassen. Man scheint sich hier in einem Bereich zu befinden, in dem das Sprachsystem ein wenig "fuzzy" wird.